# Using Index match with wildcards to find a partial match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, partial

I have seen this question asked before, but I could not understand the answer. I was hoping someone could help me with an Index match formula. with a partial match.

I use this formula :

```
=(IFERROR(INDEX($A200$:$a$250,MATCH($A1,$B$200:$B$250,0)),""))
```

To find a exact match and it works very well.
exampel :

I want to find some data that is in an collection of data and put it next to the name on a premade sheet.

Now my problem :
In this other sheet I want to do the same, but the names have a numbers next to them like this :
"John Smith 12345" There is always 5 numbers.

The numbers are in the same cell, I could make it work with making another row of names but then I would have to maintain it as well.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: As a dirty way: `=(IFERROR(INDEX($A$200:$A$250,MATCH($A1,LEFT($B$200:$B$250,LEN($B$200:$B$250)-6),0)),""))` will simply ignore the rightmost 6 characters

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wildcard:

```
 =(IFERROR(INDEX($A$200:$a$250,MATCH($A1&" ?????",$B$200:$B$250,0)),""))
```

The above will match Whatever is in `A1`, followed by a space, followed by any 5 characters

Comment: @Dirk Reichel - Works for me both with 2010 and 2013

Comment: Hi
Thank you all for your answers, I went with the wildcard posted by cybernetic_nomad, this seems to work best for me and I could understand it:)
I feel this open up a new world for me with INDEX MATCH.